# UI Python - Como Fazer

Tags: python

Escrevi um programa simples em Python, e preciso fazer uma interface gráfica pra ele, quais as opções de GUI Builder hoje?

Comment: Matheus, tente elaborar melhor a pergunta, ela está muito ampla.

Comment: A resposta do @FelipeAvelar foi suficiente. Trouxe direção e opções de pesquisa. Vou retirar a parte de "Como é feito o processo".

Comment: `quais as opções de GUI Builder hoje?` também não é uma boa pergunta para um site de perguntas e respostas, pois gerar respostas principalmente baseadas em opinioes e fica quase que impossivel determinar uma resposta correta. [Veja aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/819/3117)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem alguns módulos do [python](/questions/tagged/python) que permitem que você faça uma interface de usuário gráfica:

O módulo [TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) é uma opção bastante utilizada. Entretanto [caso você queira algo mais profissional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094369/1606920), você pode utilizar o [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) que é baseado no Qt, uma plataforma para desenvolvimento de GUI que foi [produzida pela Nokia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt).

Comment: Uma pequena correção, o **PyQT** não foi desenvolvido pela Nokia, e sim pela [Riverbank Computing](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro), originalmente sob a licença GPL. Como a Nokia tinha problemas em aceitar a licença GPL ela criou o [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide), que é praticamente igual ao **PyQT** mas tem uma licença menos restritiva (LGPL se não me engano).

Comment: Na verdade, eu me expressei mal. Eu quis dizer que o Qt foi desenvolvido pela Nokia. Apesar de não ser mais dela.

Comment: Mas o QT originalmente foi desenvolvido pela Trolltech, que por sua vez foi comprada pela Nokia. Agora até a Nokia já vendeu de novo? hehe..

Comment: Sim, como é possível ver [aqui](http://bespacoliberdade.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/direitos-comercias-do-qt-vendidos-pela-nokia/) e [aqui](http://g1.globo.com/tecnologia/noticia/2012/08/nokia-vende-unidade-de-desenvolvimento-de-aplicativos.html).

Comment: Olha só... tinha que ter a M$ por trás mesmo.. hehe. QT realmente é tudo de bom! Pior para a Nokia...